# C Select Server, double read at same time

Tags: c, sockets

How do I configure a select-server in C that can double read? Or is that not possible?

For example in a select server when the server receives something

```
read(socket,buffer,sizeof(buf));
write(socket,"Received",8);
read(socket,buffer,sizeof(buf));
```

When it gets to the second read, all other connections will be halted before the first client responds to the second read. Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Not possible. You need to keep track of the fact that you're waiting for the second response from client N in some variable somewhere. And then go back to the `select`.

Comment: yes, have a thread per connection.

Comment: So it's possible to have a select-threaded server?

Comment: IBM has a nice little set of well documented public domain code called nweb that shows how to make a basic web server in C https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aixpert/entry/how_does_a_webserver_actually_work_find_out_with_nweb58?lang=en It used fork() instead of threads, but is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes it's possible and even straightforward. As technosaurus says having a separate process per connection is another option (and a much more popular one), you may want to explore it too.